# Remove special characters with kettle, regex

Tags: regex, kettle

Writing regex expression is new to me and after browsing for quite some time without getting it right I try my luck here.

With kettle (geokettle) I would like to remove any "special characters" from values in my table.

My main aim i to only allow latin characters to remove any åæø and replace them with aao. Would also like to wash out special characters like !"#$%&/\ and replace with a punctuation or comma.

Is this a done with a simple expression?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this "[Special Character Remover](https://github.com/rishuatgithub/Pentaho/tree/master/SpecialCharacterRemover/SpecialCharacterRemover-ver-1.1.0)" plugin.

try reading this [blog](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2015/01/13/special-character-remover-version-1-1-0-pentaho-kettle-step-plugin/) and check if it fulfills your requirement.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I am running geokettle, does it work on it too? I downloaded the plugin, but i cannot recognize the path where I should put it i my catalog.

Comment: Found it under..::  GeoKettle\plugins\steps

Comment: Does it only work when the input data is Data Grid like in the example in the plog? I have a CSV input and I got up an error when i try to open the function

Comment: @geogrow I havent tested this plugin on Geokettle. It works fine in Pentaho kettle.. !!!